# Wordpress - Display text if checkbox output matches the page title

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-fields

I want to show the projects that has had it's checkbox ticked as Branding, if it's on the Branding page (i.e the page title is Branding).

To explain the code a bit:

This line show's all the checkboxes that have been ticked for each project so it will output "Branding", "Web", "Print" if they have been ticked.

```
implode(', ',get_field('categories')
```

This next line is just checking the page title is "Branding":

```
implode(', ',get_field('categories')
```

I'm trying to put these both in an if statement where it would just output the checked boxes and if they match the title then output them.

```
<?php if(implode(', ',get_field('categories')) && $grid_title == "Branding"); {
echo "testing"; 
}
?>
```

The code above shows what I want to do but it doesn't quite work.

**IMPORTANT: I'm using [this plugin](http://plugins.elliotcondon.com/advanced-custom-fields/) to create the custom checkboxes so please bear that in mind.**

=============================

**UPDATE:**
Thanks very much to Adam Kiss for solving what I asked, small update to question:

How could I code this neatly - using your answer, Branding was just one example of the check boxes, there's also several other one's like Web, Print, Social so how could I match those to the page title as well?

So it will be along the lines of if checked field equals the page title "branding" do **OR** checked field equals page title "web" **OR** checked field equals page title "print".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the function you're looking for is [`in_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php):

```
<?php
   if(
       in_array("Branding", get_field('categories')) 
       && $grid_title == "Branding"
   ){
     echo "testing";
   }
```

Note: this assumes that result of that implode is array with strings like "Branding", "Web", etc.

**Edit**: Since we're using `implode()`, I assume get_field returns type `array`, so we put the implode away (I got confused for a while)

**Edit**: Sorry, was away :]

you could use [`array_intersect`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php)

Usage:

```
$categories = get_field('categories');
$cats_iwant = array("Branding", "Print", "Design");

$inarray = array_intersect($categories, $cats_iwant);
//this '$inarray' now has values like 'Branding', 'Design' which are in both arrays

if (count($inarray) > 0) {
  //we have at least one common word ('Branding', ...)
}

//short version
if (count(array_intersect(get_field('categories'),array(
    'Branding', 'Design', 'Print'
   ))) > 0)
{
 //do stuff
}
```

Comment: Yep that's how they come out, it's getting an error - Warning: in_array() [function.in-array]: Wrong datatype for second argument in /home/teamwork/public_html/v2/wp-content/themes/default/grid.php on line 64

Comment: The implode bit by itself (ie - <?php echo implode(', ',get_field('categories'));?>) just output's the text "Branding, Web" and "Branding". Which is correct because there are two projects, the first has branding and web checked and the second has branding checked. Just need to get that to work within the array as it shows the error in the comment above.

Comment: Thanks that's great, several other people have tried and failed so really appreciate it!! I'll tick it as the answer now but I have a small update to the question which I'll add.

Comment: I've just added or to the statement.